# Undefined Type Intervention\Image\ImageServiceProvider

Tags: laravel, image

I have a problem with `intervention/image` that is driving me crazy.
I'm using Laravel 7.* , following [this](http://image.intervention.io/getting_started/installation#laravel), with `composer require intervention/image` I've installed this package. However when I have to add 
`Intervention\Image\ImageServiceProvider::class` ,
and

`'Image' => Intervention\Image\Facades\Image::class`,

in `$providers` and `$aliases` (in `app.php` arrays) the compiler keep telling me:

`Undefined type Intervention\Image\ImageServiceProvider::class`

In another istance of a project (same laravel version) the package worked perfectly.
Am I missing something?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Call to undefined method Intervention\Image\Facades\Image::make()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40353307/call-to-undefined-method-intervention-image-facades-imagemake)

Answer (score 0):

Check to make sure that you do have a **intervention/image/src** folder  inside your projects **vendor** folder.

If not, you probably need to run composer install